# Node.JS stuck at v14.20, I don't know how to update or even remove it

Tags: apt, package-management, nodejs

I don't remember how exactly I installed this version. Stupid, I know. When I do `node -v` I get `v14.20.0`. Trying to do `sudo apt-get remove node` (or nodejs) does not work.

I want to remove this version and get node v20. I also noticed I have a `n` command on my machine. This command also cannot seem to be removable easily. It seems to be some kind of node version manager, but when I ask it to install node V20, I can't seem to be able to figure out how to run it.

I am pretty sure I followed instructions here when originally installing it: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#ubuntu-versions

But if I do:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

No error, but `node -v` still returns v14. It does install `nodejs` package. But `nodejs -v` returns `v12.22.9` instead of `v20`.

I also tried using npm, since it does seem npm has the version that I see when running `node -v`. My steps:

- `sudo npm install -g npm stable`
- `sudo npm install -g node` - error: `EEXIST - /usr/local/bin/node`
- `sudo npm update -g node` - `changed 1 package in 800ms`

But after this, the version is still the same.

I tried this and there seem to be two version overlapping the one that I actually want to use, but I am not sure what installed them and why:

```
$ type -a node
node is /run/user/1000/fnm_multishells/280427_1702084033386/bin/node
node is /run/user/1000/fnm_multishells/2305083_1701177313283/bin/node
node is /usr/local/bin/node
```

Can I just delete these?